# Как отправить запрос в api и вывести данные из response?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, spa

Есть у меня условная html страничка и мой самописанный api

Есть GET запрос для получения информации о пользователе:

```
URL: {host}/user
Method: GET

Headers
- Content-Type: application/json
- Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

И ответом, в случае валидации, будет:

```
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/json
Body:
{
    "first_name": "Ivan",
    "last_name": "Ivanov",
    "phone": "89001234567",
    "document_number": "1224567890"
}
```

Как мне отправить запрос и вывести полученный ответ используя только ванильный JS и либу Jquery?

С фронтом сам по себе знаком, как и с JS, однако работать с реквестами приходится впервые. Может-быть у кого-нибудь есть примеры или даже уроки по этому поводу?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest тут все описано и пример есть

Comment: Современный аналог XMLHttpRequest - это метод fetch